# Error when install NPM navigation dependencies package installation

Tags: react-native, npm, react-navigation

when install this package
1 . npm install @react-native-community/masked-view .

it shows error like this

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: Sample_pro@0.0.1 npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR! react@"17.0.1" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10 npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view npm ERR! @react-native-community/masked-view@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-21T03_52_51_024Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, you can choose any of this:

upgrade @react-native-community/masked-view to the latest package which is accepting react@16 and react@17

downgrade your root project's react version to 16